# Saleor dashboard logging me out so quickly after very few mins

Tags: saleor

I am using the latest version of saleor dashboard and back-end (3.4.3 - 3.4.0) and the dash board is logging me out so quickly, is there anyway to prevent token expiration and save my login ?

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to change token expiration time limit in the core. Please open a github discussion in the official repo to get an advice.

Comment: I have this issue and cannot find any issues/discussions on github about it.